# How I can create 2d list with tuples?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and now I need to rewrite my code for C++ to C#.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, bool>>> board(n);
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
{
    int node1 = 0, node2 = 0;
    std::cin >> node1 >> node2;
    board[node1 - 1].push_back(std::make_pair(node2 - 1, true));
    board[node2 - 1].push_back(std::make_pair(node1 - 1, false));
}
```

It is my try, but I can`t create an array with a specified length and add the values to it.

```
List<Dictionary<int, bool>> board = new List<Dictionary<int, bool>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) board.Add(new List<Dictionary<int, bool>>);
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            String[] road = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int node1 = int.Parse(road[0]), node2 = int.Parse(road[1]);
            board[node1 - 1].Add(Dictionary<int, bool>(node2 - 1, true));
            board[node2 - 1].Add(Dictionary<int, bool>(node1 - 1, false));
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `List<Dictionary<int, bool>>`?

Comment: I tried, but I can`t create list with a specified length.

Comment: If you are only concern about length of List, then you can use [List<T>(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-ctor(system-int32)) constructor of `List<T>`

Comment: @Prasad Telkikar That only sets the list‘s capacity not length.

Comment: @ckuri, yes you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C++ code allocates an n-element vector/List of vectors/Lists of (int, bool)- Tuples.
The "verbatim" translation to to C# would be a `List<List<(int, bool)>>`, or with the n-element initialization e.g.:

`var board = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => new List<(int, bool)>()).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to `std::vector` in c# is [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0). For a tuple you can chose between [`Tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=net-6.0) and [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-6.0). So your type could be `List<List<(int, bool)>>`.

You may also consider using a [multidimensional array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays). I.e. `(int, bool)[,]`.